# Intersection point of two sequential profiles

Tags: r, math, numeric

I have two vectors of identity profiles (values between 0 and 1) and a fixed length (determined by the underlying sequence).

I would like to compute the cross points of both profiles i.e. the point where the representive profile (with higher identity) changes.

My current solution is based on calculation of the sign and product calculation of consecutive numbers. Can you imagine a more elegant way?

```
a <- c(1,1,1,0.8,0.8,0.8)
b <- c(0.8,0.8,0.8,1,1,1)

z <- sign(a - b)

res <- sapply(2:length(z),function(i){ z[i-1]*z[i] })
idx <- which(res == "-1")

plot(x=1:length(a),y=a,type="b")
points(x=1:length(b),y=b,type="b")
abline(v=idx,col="red")
```

Comment: If it is guaranteed that intersection does exist, you can use binary search. But it is sensible only for long data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you can get `idx` using `sign` and `diff`

```
which(diff(sign(a - b)) != 0)
#[1] 3
```

So if you have `a` and `b` as

```
a <- c(1,1,1,0.8,0.8,0.8,1,1)
b <- c(0.8,0.8,0.8,1,1,1,0.8,0.8)
```

This would return

```
idx <- which(diff(sign(a - b)) != 0)
idx
#[1] 3 6
```

and the plot would look like :

```
plot(x= 1:length(a),y=a,type="b")
points(x=1:length(b),y=b,type="b")
abline(v=idx,col="red")
```

[image]